# How can I have my app appear in the intent chooser only for certain urls?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing an app that can extract information from certain web pages. The idea is that when the user is within a specific url path in the browser and press the share button, my app will show up in the list of receiver apps.

I can do that easily by adding this to the manifest:

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

However, this will make my app appear on the list on all urls, also all those where it will have nothing to do. Instead I would like the app appear in the chooser only from these urls:

*www.example.com/foo/bla.html*

*www.example.com/foo/bar/blabla.html*

But not from these:

*www.example.com*

*www.foobar.com*

etc. Ie. only from within a certain path on a certain host. Also note that I do not want my app to be launched when the user clicks on links matching the criteria. It should only be invoked from the share menu.

**So my question is: How can I limit my app to show up in the intent choose only for certain urls?**

Comment: do you have the possibility to make subdomains on that URLs? like bla.example.com?

Comment: No, that is not an option.

Comment: You're entitled to vote however you want, but I don't see the logic in downvoting every answer you get. It discourages anyone else from answering and even if you don't like the facts, CommonsWares answer is informative and correct and Dharanis answer is the closest reasonable solution

Comment: Why do you say I am downvoting every answer I get? This is probably the first answer to one of my own questions I have ever downvoted. And I didn't downvote the current answer. The one I downvoted was rude, but CommonsWare have modified it in the meantime and made it much better. So I have removed the downvote. I want to add that I normally enjoy CommonsWare's answers but frankly that answer was rude. But not anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following filter to the destination Activity ..
 1. **host** your site name.
 2. **scheme** scheme of your site http or https.
 3. **path** for the file path your app should display.

```
<intent-filter>
             <data
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:scheme="http"
                android:path="/foo/bla.html"
                />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
            </category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" >
            </category>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: This makes my app respond to clicks matching urls which is not what I want. I don't want to "hijack" those urls. I only need my app to show up in the list that appears when the user presses the share button. But only when browsing those specific urls.

Comment: why don't you try <grant-uri-permission> along with above code...?...refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/grant-uri-permission-element.html..

Answer (score 3):

> How can I limit my app to show up in the intent choose only for certain urls?

You can't. `ACTION_SEND` has no notion of "only from certain URLs", or "only from certain WhatsApp users", or "only from left-handed Alaskan pipe-welders".

This is not significantly different than any other activity. An `<intent-filter>` only controls what the `Intent` is being delivered *to*. Nothing controls what the `Intent` is delivered from, with the exception of security-related items (permissions, whether or not the component is exported, etc.).

So, with `ACTION_VIEW`, the URL is something being delivered *to* another activity ("I wish to view this URL"). This works because the URL is turned into the `Uri` of the `Intent`, and that can be filtered upon via `<data>` elements in the `<intent-filter>`.

But `ACTION_SEND` doesn't have to have a URL, and even if there is one, it is merely payload in the form of an extra. It is not something that can be filtered upon.

Hence, what you want is not supported.

Answer (score -1):

Use [pathPrefix](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html)

```
    <intent-filter>
         <data
            android:host="www.example.com"
            android:scheme="http"
            android:pathPrefix="/foo/"
            />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
        </category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" >
        </category>
    </intent-filter>
```